# Interchanging expectation under summation

Tags: probability

Suppose $X \geq 0 $ almost surely and $\mathbb{E} \{X \} $ is finite. IF I have a sequence of events $\{ A_n \}$ pairwise disjoint, Can I perform the following:

$$ \mathbb{E} \bigg\{ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} X 1_{A_n} \bigg\} = \sum \mathbb{E} \{ X 1_{A_n} \} $$

??

I am thinking of using the following theorem( Monotone convergence theorem) : If r.v's $(X_n)$ are positive and increasing almost surely to $X$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E} \{X_n \} = \mathbb{ E} \{X\} $

I was thinking on using $X_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} X 1_{A_k} $. We know by hypothesis $X_n \geq 0 $ and $X_n$ are increasing a moreover $X_n \to \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} X 1_{A_k} $ and so by the theorem

$$ \lim \mathbb{E} \{ \sum_{k=1}^{n} X 1_{A_k} \} = \mathbb{E} \{ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} X 1_{A_k} \} $$ and we know

$$ \lim \mathbb{E} \{ \sum_{k=1}^n X 1 _{A_k} \} = \lim \sum_{k=1}^n \mathbb{E} \{ X 1_{A_k} \} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{E} \{X 1_{A_k} \} $$

Is this a correct argument?

Comment: This is valid since your rv's are positive a.s. In fact it is proved as a theorem in most books.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your argumentation is correct. If we use the dominated convergence theorem instead of the monotone convergence theorem, then we can even drop the assumption on non-negativity of $X$ (note that the dominated convergence theorem is applicable because the events are disjoint).